# Скрыть своих эмоций (падежи)

Tags: падежи

Как правильно говорить: «я не мог скрыть своих удивления и раздражения» или «я не мог скрыть свои удивление и раздражение»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сказала:«*Я не мог скрыть своего удивления и раздражения*»

Правило выбора падежа:

> При глаголе (а также причастии или деепричастии) с отрицанием
>   дополнение стоит обычно в родительном падеже: Я помню море пред
>   грозою. (П.) — Я не помню утра более голубого и свежего. (Л.)
>   Примечание. При обозначении конкретных, определённых предметов после
>   отрицания может употребляться и винительный падеж; при обозначении
>   отвлечённых понятий, как правило, — родительный падеж: Он не купил
>   себе журнал. Он не купил себе журнала. Но: Он не имеет права. Он не
>   учёл всех
>   возможностей.https://zakon.today/russkiy-yazyik/dopolnenie-forme-roditelnogo-padeja-pri-39920.html

У нас отвлечённые понятия, следовательно, родительный падеж.

Согласование в числе:

> Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным -
>   однородным членам, может стоять в форме и единственного, и
>   множественного числа. Предпочитается употреблять определение в
>   единственном числе, если: • однородные существительные связаны
>   разделительным союзом (написать интересный роман или повесть, купить
>   плюшевую собаку или кошку); • по смыслу ясно, что определение
>   относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к остальным
>   (каждый завод и фабрика, создание новой оперы и балета). В
>   официально-деловой речи определение во втором случае во избежание
>   двусмысленности ставится во множественном числе. Выбирается форма
>   множественного числа определения, если может возникнуть неясность:
>   относится ли оно только к ближайшему существительному или ко всему
>   ряду однородных членов (старинные шкаф и стол, мелко нарезанные зелень
>   и мясо).

В нашем случае  по смыслу ясно, что определение относится  к двум существительным, значит, предпочтительно единственное число: **своего удивления и раздражения**

https://psyera.ru/soglasovanie-opredeleniya-s-sushchestvitelnymi-odnorodnymi-chlenami_8728.htm